# Iterator trouble in a circular doubly linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

For an assignment, I am to build a circular doubly linked list. Whenever I try and print out the list though, it always leaves the last element out, and I can't figure out why. From what I understand about iterators everything should be working, but something is happening in print so that my lists are printing one short.

Here's main:

```
int main(void)
{
    cdll mycdll(3,'X');
    cout << "mycdll: " << mycdll << endl;
    cout << mycdll << endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The object is created with this:

```
cdll::cdll(size_t n_elements, datatype datum) 
        :m_size(0), head(nullptr), tail(nullptr)
{
    if(n_elements <= 0)
        throw out_of_range("Empty cdll");
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n_elements; ++i)
        push_front(datum);
}
```

And this is where I print:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& sout, const cdll& x) 
{
    cdll::iterator p = x.begin(); // gets x.h
    sout << "(";

    while(p != x.end())
    {
         sout << *p;
         if(p->next != x.end())
            sout << ",";
         ++p; // advances iterator using next
    }
        sout << ")\n";
        return sout;
}
```

And in case it helps, this is pushBack()

```
void cdll::push_front(datatype datum) 
{
    node* temp = new node(datum, tail, head);
    m_size++;
    if (!empty())
   { // was a nonempty cdll
        head->prev = temp;
        tail->next = temp;
        head = temp;

    }
    else 
    {
        head = tail = temp;
    }
}
```

The output I get is `mycdll(X,X,)`, and I'm expecting `mycdll(X,X,X)`. I'm doing something wrong with the iterators in `print()`. Any ideas?

Comment: How is your `end()` implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your end() returns tail, do{ }while(); instead of while(); should fix the problem.

Other way you will always miss the last item, as the while() condition will fail on tail with p pointing to this item.

Comment: This is my end(): iterator end() const {return tail;}                      Doing it as a do{}while(); has changed it to output the following: "mycdll(X,X)" so I'm still missing the last one. I think the problem is I want to print the tail element too, but since end() returns tail, the while loop fails the conditional before printing it.